# Python import list of exceptions from string

Tags: python

My code its something like this:

```
if Number == 1:

except 1
except 2


If Number2 == 2:

except 1
except 2
```

How i can import a list of exceptions? without writing it everytime? something like:

```
ListExcept = ['ExceptError1', 'ExceptError2']


if Number == 1:

except ListExcept
```

Sorry for my bad example and english

Comment: you want to raise two errors?

Comment: You only posted the exception handling part. When do you want to raise those exceptions?

Comment: Sorry, it is entirely unclear what you are trying to do. The mock code shown is largely meaningless. Are you trying to *catch* an exception or *raise* it? Is there a reason why you have a list of exception type *names* instead of exception types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A try clause can have any number of except clauses to handle different exceptions, however, only one will be executed in case an exception occurs.

We can use a `tuple` of values to specify multiple exceptions in an except clause.

You cannot use `list`!

---

TEST 1

```
try:
    # do something
    a = 10
    b = 0
    c = a/b

except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError):
    # handle multiple exceptions
    # TypeError and ZeroDivisionError
    pass
   
del a
del b

try:
    # do something
    b = 0
    a = '10'
    c = a/b

except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError):
    # handle multiple exceptions
    # TypeError and ZeroDivisionError
    pass
```

```
## No ERRORS
```

---

TEST 2

```
del a
del b

try:
    # do something
    a = 10
    c = a/b

except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError):
    # handle multiple exceptions
    # TypeError and ZeroDivisionError
    pass
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3726f056c576> in <module>()
     30     # do something
     31     a = 10
---> 32     c = a/b
     33 
     34 except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError):

NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

---

TEST 3

FIXING

```
## fixing above error
try:
    # do something
    a = 10
    c = a/b

except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError, NameError):
    # handle multiple exceptions
    # TypeError and ZeroDivisionError and NameError
    pass
```

Comment: This seems unrelated to what the question is trying to do, namely handling (be it raising or catching) exceptions *from a list of strings*.

Comment: I meant this, but how can I respond to every mistake? if for example it is TypeError, I want that when the error is caught, then a
print (Exact error) without using an if else